# После отключения синхронизации потоков время выполнения не меняется

Tags: c++, алгоритм, оптимизация, олимпиада

У задачи есть ограничение по времени и мой код в него не укладывается. На просторах интернетов узнал, что можно отключить синхронизацию для уменьшения времени считывания входных данных.

UPD: вот весь код, и вопрос: из-за ввода чисел я теряю много время или же всё-таки алгоритм кривой?
Задача: http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1880

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);

    int amount_of_numbers_1st, amount_of_numbers_2nd, amount_of_numbers_3rd;
    int amount_of_successful_numbers=0;
    int **numbers = new int*[3];

    cin>>amount_of_numbers_1st;
    numbers[0] = new int[amount_of_numbers_1st];
    for(int i=0; i<amount_of_numbers_1st; i++)
        cin>>numbers[0][i];

    cin>>amount_of_numbers_2nd;
    numbers[1] = new int[amount_of_numbers_2nd];
    for(int i=0; i<amount_of_numbers_2nd; i++)
        cin>>numbers[1][i];

    cin>>amount_of_numbers_3rd;
    numbers[2] = new int[amount_of_numbers_3rd];
    for(int i=0; i<amount_of_numbers_3rd; i++)
        cin>>numbers[2][i];

    int j=0, k=0, i=0;
    start_of_1st:
    while(i<amount_of_numbers_1st)
    while(j<amount_of_numbers_2nd)
    {
        if(numbers[0][i] > numbers[1][j])
            j++;
        else
            if(numbers[0][i] == numbers[1][j])
///////////////////////////////////////////////
            while(k<amount_of_numbers_3rd)
            {
                if(numbers[0][i] > numbers[2][k])
                    k++;
                else
                    if(numbers[0][i] == numbers[2][k])
                    {
                        amount_of_successful_numbers++;
                        i++; k++; j++; goto start_of_1st;
                    }
                    else
                        {i++; j++; goto start_of_1st;}
            }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
            else
                {i++; goto start_of_1st;}
    }
    cout<<amount_of_successful_numbers;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что ввод данных занимает большую часть времени, используемого задачей? (Олимпиадники иногда scanf предпочитают иостримщине). Может, дело всё-таки в алгоритме обработки данных (или чего там внутри делается)?

Comment: @MBo Насколько мне известно - iostream не уступает (а иногда опережает) scanf по времени, если отключить синхронизацию C и С++ потоков. А на счет обработки данных: вряд-ли, т.к. старался снизить количество операций как только мог.

Comment: Каков размер массивов, какое время на задачу отводится, и что за задача вообще?

Comment: http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1880

Comment: *"единственный кусок кода, где происходит ввод данных"* На всякий случай, у вас ведь нет *вывода* до `sync_with_stdio`?

Comment: Ввод 12000 чисел вряд ли займет полсекунды, а вот неудачный алгоритм - может.

Comment: Краткое резюме: не выявив проблемное место вы решили оптимизировать то, что попалось под руку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никогда не пытайтесь оптимизировать использование спичек в квартире алкоголика.

Вот такое тупое решение "в лоб"

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<int> a, b, c, d;
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0, x; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cin >> x;
        a.push_back(x);
    }
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0, x; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cin >> x;
        b.push_back(x);
    }
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0, x; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cin >> x;
        c.push_back(x);
    }
    set_intersection(a.begin(),a.end(),b.begin(),b.end(),back_inserter(d));
    a.clear();
    set_intersection(d.begin(),d.end(),c.begin(),c.end(),back_inserter(a));
    cout << a.size() << endl;
}
```

спокойно проходит все тесты... Время работы - 0.031 с на сайте. Сложность - линейная (при том, что у вас она на глаз - N^3)...

Если не хотите использовать `set_intersection` - его нетрудно написать самостоятельно:

```
vector<int> intersect(const vector<int>& a, const vector<int>& b)
{
    vector<int> c;
    for(int ia = 0, ib = 0; ia < a.size() && ib < b.size();)
    {
        if (a[ia] < b[ib]) ++ia;
        else if (b[ib] < a[ia]) ++ib;
        else
        {
            c.push_back(a[ia]);
            ++ia; ++ib;
        }
    }
    return c;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<int> a, b, c, d;
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0, x; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cin >> x;
        a.push_back(x);
    }
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0, x; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cin >> x;
        b.push_back(x);
    }
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0, x; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cin >> x;
        c.push_back(x);
    }
    cout << intersect(intersect(a,b),c).size() << endl;
}
```

Это решение проходит за 0.015с.

Выделяю жирными буквами:

**если на олимпиадной задаче решение не проходит по времени - меняйте алгоритм!**